# How can I encrypt link for a download path for ym client?

Tags: encryption, hyperlink, download

I have some files in my ftp that I need to share to different clients. 
I use Wordpress, but these files are "outside" wordpress.

I would like to share to my client not th edirect link

www.mysite.com/download/book/book.pdf

but something different, something encripted, better if with "expiration " time. 
do you know a way to obtain such result? Some PRO service maybe?

As you understand, I don't know nothing about code, but I don't know where to ask...

Thank you for every suggestion! =)

Comment: Why would you even want to encrypt the link ?

Comment: It's very simple: I don't want that the client will share this link =)  https://www.temporary-url.com/ This website is great, I think

Comment: So You don't really want encryption, but link shortening/redirection page :) The simplest idea would be to take the link and generate a random sequence of characters, technically it could be hashcode, but collisions may be an issue here. Then you could store the generated sequence with some kind of the key-value store (e.g. Redis). When User would enter your site and pass the sequence that You have sent him, You could take the real address from the store and return it to allow redirection. Depending on the selected store You can get the TTL for the given link out-of-the-box.